# Random process at 25% CPU usage

Tags: windows-7, windows, cpu, process

I have strange problem. Sometimes, often after few minutes of using PC a random process get 25% of CPU usage and it stays at that. Sometimes it's chrome, bittorrent, text editor or something else. And only one process is at 25%, never multiple. When i end that process, for example, I kill chrome.exe and after few seconds bittorrent.exe gets 25% of usage. I scanned my windows few times with different antiviruses and never found nothing. Number of 25 is constant, it's not 24, 26, it's locked at 25%.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL7sq.png]

Comment: this means a single thread process uses 1 CPU core for 100%. run this: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD I'll take a look what is wrong. If you want to try it yourself, follow this: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis

Comment: @magicandre1981 http://www.mediafire.com/download/lczie22gijc6hc5/HighCPUUsage.rar Here you go. It took a ~1 min and stopped by itself.

Comment: In the trace you gave me, I see the CPU usage comes from opening Registry keys. You need to add **+REGISTRY+REG_HIVE** after **latency** in the commandline so that I can see which keys are accessed.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Done: https://www.mediafire.com/?agslcn6c5nia97q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bittorrent tries to open the key `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal\AppInfo`, but this fails with `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`

[image]

This causes the CPU usage.

Comment: I've tried changing permission but still the same, any advice? :)

Comment: I have no idea why bittorrent tries to access this key so often. Ask this the support of the tool.

Comment: Probably, it tries while it can't access. Is not just bittorrent, sometimes is chrome or some else process...

Comment: also provide a trace of the chrome cpu usage so that I can look at it.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/osyzh7ikoe33gq4/HighCPUUsage(3).rar
Here is example with Lightshot.exe using 25% (tool for taking screenshots)

Comment: still registry activity. This time opening the key **HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\control\SafeBoot\minimal\AppMgmt** which also fails with **STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED**